# __NSCFNumber stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters unrecognized selector error

Tags: ios, objective-c

So Im new in programming with Objective-c. I want to make  request with HTTP POST Method.The parameter that i'm sending is of type int.

I'm getting this error :

```
[__NSCFNumber stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000048d3
```

at this line of code :

```
return [string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:allowed];
```

The whole Code:

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
[request setHTTPBody:[self httpBodyForParameters:params]];

NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"dataTaskWithRequest error: %@", error);
    }
    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
        NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
        if (statusCode != 200) {
            NSLog(@"Expected responseCode == 200; received %ld", (long)statusCode);
        }}
    NSError *parseError;
    id responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
     if (!responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON parse error: %@", parseError);
    } else {
    NSLog(@"responseObject = %@", responseObject);
     }
    NSLog(@"print123");

}];
[task resume];
}

- (NSData *)httpBodyForParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters {
NSMutableArray *parameterArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [parameters enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSString *obj, BOOL *stop) {
NSString *param = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", [self percentEscapeString:key], [self percentEscapeString:obj]];
    [parameterArray addObject:param];
}];

NSString *string = [parameterArray componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];

    return [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

- (NSString *)percentEscapeString:(NSString *)string {
NSCharacterSet *allowed = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._~"];
return [string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:allowed];
}
```

Comment: One of the items in your parameters dictionary is an `NSNumber`,  not an `NSString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Paulw11 is right that the error is the result of a number being treated as a string.  An immediate (but a little clunky) fix is to be less committed to the type of values you find when enumerating the dictionary...

```
// notice we change the type of obj id, not NSString*
[parameters enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    // now, test for it's type and treat accordingly
    NSString *objString = ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString self]])? [self percentEscapeString:obj] : [obj stringValue];
    NSString *param = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", [self percentEscapeString:key], objString];
    [parameterArray addObject:param];
}];
```

But this brittle solution now works only for strings and numbers.  If you can convince the server to accept JSON, then the request code can be simplified *and generalized* like this...

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

// params is your original (serializable) dictionary
NSError *error;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: params options:0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLSessionTask *task =  // ...
```

Comment: @Dzi, Happy to hear. You can indicate that by marking it correct.

Comment: Can you help me with something else ? I have this error Expected responseCode == 200; received 500

Comment: @Dzi, 500 means an internal error on the server side.